# Change object type at runtime maintaining functionality

Tags: c#, reflection, types, runtime

#### Long story short

Say I have the following code:

```
// a class like this 
class FirstObject {
    public Object OneProperty {
        get;
        set;
    }

    // (other properties)

    public Object OneMethod() {
        // logic
    }
}

// and another class with properties and methods names 
// which are similar or exact the same if needed 
class SecondObject {
    public Object OneProperty {
        get;
        set;
    }

    // (other properties)

    public Object OneMethod(String canHaveParameters) {
        // logic
    }
}

// the consuming code would be something like this 
public static void main(String[] args) {
    FirstObject myObject=new FirstObject();

    // Use its properties and methods
    Console.WriteLine("FirstObject.OneProperty value: "+myObject.OneProperty);
    Console.WriteLine("FirstObject.OneMethod returned value: "+myObject.OneMethod());

    // Now, for some reason, continue to use the
    // same object but with another type
    // -----> CHANGE FirstObject to SecondObject HERE <-----

    // Continue to use properties and methods but
    // this time calls were being made to SecondObject properties and Methods
    Console.WriteLine("SecondObject.OneProperty value: "+myObject.OneProperty);
    Console.WriteLine("SecondObject.OneMethod returned value: "+myObject.OneMethod(oneParameter));
}
```

Is it possible to change `FirstObject` type to `SecondObject` and continue to use it's properties and methods?

I've total control over `FirstObject`, but `SecondObject` is *sealed* and totally out of my scope!

May I achieve this through reflection? How? What do you think of the work that it might take to do it? Obviously both class can be a LOT more complex than the example above.

Both class can have templates like `FirstObject<T>` and `SecondObject<T>` which is intimidating me to use reflection for such a task!

---

#### Problem in reality

I've tried to state my problem the easier way for the sake of simplicity and to try to extract some knowledge to solve it but, by looking to the answers, it seems obvious to me that, to help me, you need to understand my real problem because changing object type is only the tip of the iceberg.

I'm developing a **Workflow Definition API**. The main objective is to have a API able to be **reusable** on top of any engine I might want to use(CLR through WF4, NetBPM, etc.).

By now I'm writing the **middle layer** to translate that API to WF4 to run workflows through the CLR.

- **What I've already accomplished**

  The API concept, at this stage, is somehow similar to WF4 with `ActivityStates` with In/Out `Arguments` and `Data`(`Variables`) running through the `ActivityStates` using their arguments.

  Very simplified API in *pseudo-code*:

  ```
  class Argument {
      object Value;
  }

  class Data {
      String Name;
      Type ValueType;
      object Value;
  }

  class ActivityState {
      String DescriptiveName;
  }

  class MyIf: ActivityState {
      InArgument Condition;
      ActivityState Then;
      ActivityState Else;
  }

  class MySequence: ActivityState {
      Collection<Data> Data;
      Collection<ActivityState> Activities;
  }
  ```

  My initial approach to translate this to WF4 was too run through the `ActivitiesStates` graph and do a somehow **direct assignment of properties**, using reflection where needed.

  Again simplified *pseudo-code*, something like:

  ```
  new Activities.If() {
      DisplayName=myIf.DescriptiveName,
      Condition=TranslateArgumentTo_WF4_Argument(myIf.Condition),
      Then=TranslateActivityStateTo_WF4_Activity(myIf.Then),
      Else=TranslateActivityStateTo_WF4_Activity(myIf.Else)
  }

  new Activities.Sequence() {
      DisplayName=mySequence.DescriptiveName,
      Variables=TranslateDataTo_WF4_Variables(mySequence.Variables),
      Activities=TranslateActivitiesStatesTo_WF4_Activities(mySequence.Activities)
  }
  ```

  At the end of the translation I would have an executable `System.Activities.Activity` object. I've already accomplished this easily.
- **The big issue**

  A big issue with this approach appeared when I began the `Data` object to `System.Activities.Variable` translation. The problem is WF4 separates the workflow execution from the context. Because of that both `Arguments` and `Variables` are `LocationReferences` that must be accessed through `var.Get(context)` function for the engine to know where they are at runtime.

  Something like this is easily accomplished using WF4:

  ```
  Variable<string> var1=new Variable<string>("varname1", "string value");
  Variable<int> var2=new Variable<int>("varname2", 123);

  return new Sequence {
      Name="Sequence Activity",
      Variables=new Collection<Variable> { var1, var2 },
      Activities=new Collection<Activity>(){
          new Write() {
              Name="WriteActivity1",
              Text=new InArgument<string>(
                  context => 
                      String.Format("String value: {0}", var1.Get(context)))
          },
          new Write() {
              //Name = "WriteActivity2",
              Text=new InArgument<string>(
                  context => 
                      String.Format("Int value: {0}", var2.Get(context)))
          }
      }
  };
  ```

  but if I want to represent the same workflow through my API:

  ```
  Data<string> var1=new Data<string>("varname1", "string value");
  Data<int> var2=new Data<int>("varname2", 123);

  return new Sequence() {
      DescriptiveName="Sequence Activity",
      Data=new Collection<Data> { var1, var2 },
      Activities=new Collection<ActivityState>(){
          new Write() {
              DescriptiveName="WriteActivity1",
              Text="String value: "+var1 // <-- BIG PROBLEM !!
          },
          new Write() {
              DescriptiveName="WriteActivity2",
              Text="Int value: "+Convert.ToInt32(var2) // ANOTHER BIG PROBLEM !!
          }
      }
  };
  ```

  I end up with a **BIG PROBLEM** when using `Data` objects as `Variable`s. I really don't know how to allow the developer, using my API, to use `Data` objects wherever who wants(just like in WF4) and later translate that `Data` to `System.Activities.Variable`.

---

#### Solutions come to mind

If you now understand my problem, the `FirstObject` and `SecondObject` are the `Data` and `System.Activities.Variable` **respectively**. Like I said translate `Data` to `Variable` is just the tip of the iceberg because I might use `Data.Get()` in my code and don't know how to translate it to `Variable.Get(context)` while doing the translation.

Solutions that I've tried or thought of:

- **Solution 1**

  Instead of a direct translation of properties I would develop `NativeActivites` for each flow-control activity(`If`, `Sequence`, `Switch`, ...) and make use of `CacheMetadata()` function to specify `Arguments` and `Variables`. The problem remains because they are both accessed through `var.Get(context)`.
- **Solution 2**

  Give my `Data` class its own `Get()` function. It would be only an abstract method, without logic inside that it would, somehow, translate to `Get()` function of `System.Activities.Variable`. Is this even possible using C#? Guess not! Another problem is that a `Variable.Get()` has one parameter.
- **Solution 3**

  The **worst solution** that I thought of was `CIL-manipulation`. Try to replace the code where `Data/Argument` is used with `Variable/Argument` code. This smells like a nightmare to me. I know next to nothing about `System.reflection.Emit` and even if I learn it my guess is that it would take ages ... and might not even be possible to do it.

Sorry if I ended up introducing a bigger problem but I'm really stuck here and desperately needing a tip/path to go on.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish with this?  Are you trying to extend the functionality of FirstObject in some way or something else?

Comment: @craig-suchanec It's a pretty big text but, like you said, I really needed to explain it in depth. I'm afraid my initial question is just the tip of the iceberg.

Comment: You should probably repost this as a WF4 question so that the right experts see it

Comment: Already done that and earned the Thumbleweed bagde for that   :\ Not a single comment. I guess its because it's not so much a WF4 question but more a matter of programming approach.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is called "duck typing" (if it looks like a duck and quacks like a duck you can call methods on it as though it really were a duck).  Declare myObject as dynamic instead of as a specific type and you should then be good to go.

EDIT: to be clear, this requires .NET 4.0

`dynamic myObject = new FirstObject();`

`// do stuff`

`myObject = new SecondObject();`

`// do stuff again`

Comment: @robert-levy In my case I can't do that mainly because I've to construct one object with the other object's data and that's just the tip of the iceberg.  Anyway, I've edited the initial question with the real-world problem. Hope you guys can give me some tips/insight to follow. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Reflection isn't necessarily the right task for this.  If `SecondObject` is out of your control, your best option is likely to just make an extension method that instantiates a new copy of it and copies across the data, property by property.

You could use reflection for the copying process, and work that way, but that is really a separate issue.

Comment: @reed-copsey That is somehow what I'm doing now. Maybe you can check my last edit and give some feedback. A little WF4 knowledge may be required. I tried to approach the question in a simpler manner and extract whatever you guys had to say but I'm afraid that only presenting the real problem I can really explain myself and you can give me proper insight. Thanks!